# Is it possible to set an OpenEdge 11.6.4 database in an Apache TomCat?

Tags: tomcat, openedge, progress-4gl, progress-db

we use a client-server Openedge 11.6.4 database hosted in Windows Server, and Windows clients.

We need some devices (like barcode scanners) to send and receive data from the database.
So, I need to set the database (or a partial copy) in a webserver.

But my employer won't buy a PAS license, nor Datadirect.

So, is it possible to set the database in a standard Apache TomCat?

Anyone knows if that could work?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "set the database in"? You can, of course, install OpenEdge on the same server as Tomcat but that does not, by itself, enable any sort of communications with Tomcat.

You are apparently aware of PASOE for communicating with Tomcat and that would, obviously, be the "correct" approach as it is modern and supported (although you really should upgrade to OpenEdge 11.7). In an 11.6 environment another option would be "webspeed" and "classic appserver" but there is no future in either of those.

There are also many "poor man's" means for communicating from the OpenEdge database to web applications. You could, for instance, write some old-fashioned "cgi" scripts. That obviously has lots of limitations and downsides and, ultimately, will probably cost more in development time and maintenance than simply going with PASOE would but if your employer prefers to be "penny wise and pound foolish" that, or something similar, is a path that you could pursue.